# EF6 duplicate entries on related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Ok, so I'm really frustrated with the duplication issues of EF6. I have searched the forum extensively and tried different things, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

My base model is a trainingprogram, that consists of many blocks, which in turn hold a list of circuits. Every circuit holds a number of exercisesets and progressions for each exercise. All the relevant parts of the model are in the minimal workin example below.

I have a controller that I use to persist training programs to the DB. Whenever I call dbcontext.SaveChanges(), my database i populated with duplicates of the related entities, although I have tried setting the state to unchanged, attaching the enities to the context and what not. Pretty much everything gets duplicated - exercises, categories and progressionschemes.

This is really a blocker, so any help is appreciated.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Add")]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddProgram(TrainingProgram program)
    {
        int id = -1;
        try
        {
            using (var dbcontext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                foreach (TrainingBlock b in program.Blocks)
                    foreach (ExercisePairing c in b.Circuits)
                    {
                        foreach (ProgressionScheme ps in c.Progressions.Select(x => x.Progression).Distinct().ToList())
                        {
                            var ep = dbcontext.Progressions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == ps.Name && p.Id == ps.Id);
                            if (ep is null)
                                dbcontext.Progressions.Attach(ps);
                            //dbcontext.Entry(ps).State = EntityState.Unchanged;// Attach(ps);
                        }

                        foreach (Exercise s in c.Sets.Select(x => x.Exercise).Distinct().ToList())
                        {
                            //dbcontext.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                            //dbcontext.Entry(s.Category).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                            dbcontext.ExerciseCategories.Attach(s.Category);
                            dbcontext.Exercises.Attach(s);
                        }
                    }

                dbcontext.TrainingPrograms.AddOrUpdate(program);
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                id = program.Id;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
    }

    public class ExercisePairing:BaseClass
    {
        private List<ExerciseSet> sets = new List<ExerciseSet>();

        private List<ProgressionForExercise> progressions = new List<ProgressionForExercise>();


        private int id;
        ...
        ...
    }
}

public class ProgressionForExercise:BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private Exercise exercise;
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public int ProgressionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExerciseId")]
    public Exercise Exercise 
    {
        get => exercise;
        set 
        {
            exercise = value;
            ExerciseId = exercise.Id;
        } 
    }

    private ProgressionScheme progression;
    [ForeignKey("ProgressionId")]
    public ProgressionScheme Progression 
    { 
        get =>progression ; 
        set
        {
            progression = value;
            ProgressionId = progression.Id;
        }
    }
}

public class Exercise : BaseClass
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string description;
    private string videourl;
    private ExerciseCategory category;

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public ExerciseCategory Category
    {
        get => category;
        set
        {
            category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get => id;
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
...
...
}


public class ExerciseCategory:BaseClass
{
    private string name;
    private int id;

    [Key]
    public int Id
    {
        get => id;
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
...
...
}

public class ProgressionScheme:BaseClass
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string description;

    public int Id
    {
        get => id;
        set 
        { 
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
...
...
}
```

**EDIT**

I now solved the issue by basically re-wrtiting my controller code like so:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Add")]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddProgram(TrainingProgram program)
    {
        int id = -1;
        try
        {
            using (var dbcontext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                TrainingProgram tp = new TrainingProgram();
                tp.Title = program.Title;
                tp.Remarks = program.Remarks;
                tp.CreationDate = program.CreationDate;
                tp.Creator = program.Creator;

                tp.Blocks = new List<TrainingBlock>();
                foreach (TrainingBlock b in program.Blocks)
                {
                    TrainingBlock tb = new TrainingBlock();
                    tb.Title = b.Title;
                    tb.Remarks = b.Remarks;
                    tb.Circuits = new List<ExercisePairing>();
                    foreach (ExercisePairing c in b.Circuits)
                    {
                        ExercisePairing ep = new ExercisePairing();
                        ep.Sets = new List<ExerciseSet>();
                        foreach(ExerciseSet s in c.Sets)
                        {
                            ExerciseSet es = new ExerciseSet();
                            Exercise ex = dbcontext.Exercises.Find(s.Exercise.Id);
                            es.Exercise = ex;

                            ExerciseCategory ec = dbcontext.ExerciseCategories.Find(s.Exercise.Category.Id);
                            es.Exercise.Category = ec;

                            es.Reps = s.Reps;
                            es.Intensity = s.Intensity;
                            es.Unit = s.Unit;

                            ep.Sets.Add(es);
                        }

                        ep.Progressions = new List<ProgressionForExercise>();
                        foreach (ProgressionForExercise pro in c.Progressions)
                        {
                            Exercise ex = dbcontext.Exercises.Find(pro.Exercise.Id);
                            ProgressionScheme ps = dbcontext.Progressions.Find(pro.Progression.Id);
                            ProgressionForExercise p4e = new ProgressionForExercise();
                            p4e.Exercise = ex;
                            p4e.Progression = ps;
                            ep.Progressions.Add(p4e);
                        }

                        tb.Circuits.Add(ep);
                    }

                    tp.Blocks.Add(tb);
                }

                dbcontext.TrainingPrograms.AddOrUpdate(tp);
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                id = tp.Id;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
    }
```

So in essence, I am avoiding the duplicates by only using the very objects that are present in the Context. Although this works, I am not sure if I am happy with that. If a simple CRUD peration takes that much code, I fail to see the upside of using EF VS simply using an SQL insert statement, which would be much more efficient in this case IMHO. Also, why does EF ignore the primary keys and insist on using its wn instances of my enitities? All of this is very strange.

Comment: What does `OnPropertyChanged ` do when setting the Id?

Comment: Just notify Xamarin Forms on the client that an update is due.